# Excel VBA, Copying info to other sheet but with random names

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, range

I'm having a problem with my excel program. I want to make the names and the telephone numbers to paste at the other sheet, but names must be sorted randomly and the phone numbers must be the same. For Example at the first sheet i have Kalin Kalinov +22222222 and Martin Martinov +99119911 and at the other sheet after the copy paste action they must be like Martin Martinov +99119911 and Kalin Kalinov +22222222.

```
Sub GenerateNames()
Dim ssheet1 As Worksheet
Dim rnsheet As Worksheet
Set ssheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rnsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RandomNames")

ssheet1.Range("A3:A70").Copy rnsheet.Range("A3:A70")
ssheet1.Range("B3:B70").Copy rnsheet.Range("B3:B70")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add something like this, and apply it either on the source sheet or on the target sheet:

```
Range("C3").Formula = "=RAND()"
Range("C3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C3:C70")

Range("A:C").Sort key1:=Range("C3"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

It creates a column of random values, used for sorting. You might want to delete it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub randomName()
Dim ws As String, ws2 As String, rg As Range, rg2 As Range
Dim DataRange As Variant, i As Integer
Dim n As Integer, tmp As String
Dim nData As Integer
      '== set by user
            nData = 70        '== data size
            ws = "sheet1":                ws2 = "RandomNames"     '== sheets name
            Set rg = Sheets(ws).Cells(3, 1):            Set rg2 = Sheets(ws2).Cells(3, 1)       '=range with start row
      '== Run
            rg2.Resize(nData, 2).Value = rg.Resize(nData, 2).Value
            DataRange = rg.Resize(nData).Value
            For i = 1 To UBound(DataRange)
                  n = CLng(Rnd(i) * Second(Now) * 100) Mod UBound(DataRange) + 1
                  If i <> n Then tmp = DataRange(n, 1):          DataRange(n, 1) = DataRange(i, 1):         DataRange(i, 1) = tmp
            Next i
            rg2.Resize(nData) = DataRange:            Set rg = Nothing:            Set rg2 = Nothing
End Sub
```